# ROS Answers SE migration: IK with KDL

Tags: ros, ik, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone!
I have a similar problem and I solved it like described in this topic [ros-users](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/IK-with-KDL-td1867716.html).
Program works fine, but when I try calculate joints values more different than inital values, IK solver not found.
Source files: [leg_kinematics.cpp](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/file/n4020491/leg_kinematics.cpp)
[hp_chainiksolverpos_nr_jl.cpp](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/file/n4020491/hp_chainiksolverpos_nr_jl.cpp)

For example.
Inital frame of end-effector : 0.14208; -0.14555; -0.11145
Inital joints : 0, 0, 0

Desired frame : 0.16574, -0.1868, -0.08033

(delta_twist from hp_chainiksolverpos_nr_jl)

```
[ INFO] [1386694221.094697005]: delta_twist.vel 1: 0.023664 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.041252 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.031120  
[ INFO] [1386694221.094781119]: delta_twist.vel 1: 0.003682 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.006420 delta_twist.vel 3: -0.009216  
[ INFO] [1386694221.094833633]: 
Joint 1: -0.000007 
Joint 2: 0.245227 
Joint 3: 0.211637
```

---

Desired frame : 0.098897, -0.25073, 0.053264 ( joints: 0.46, 0.73, 0.84)

```
[ INFO] [1386694869.786644209]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: -0.043179 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.105182 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.164714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.786831916]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: 0.024520 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.157306 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.083648 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.786888482]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: -0.016815 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.191048 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.786932308]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: 0.036921 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.185430 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.786992199]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: -0.014347 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.214840 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.787067596]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: 0.036921 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.185430 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.787110975]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: -0.014347 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.214840 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.787151938]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: 0.036921 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.185430 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.787192158]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: -0.014347 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.214840 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 [0m 
[0m[ INFO] [1386694869.787235519]: 
delta_twist.vel 1: 0.036921 delta_twist.vel 2: -0.185430 delta_twist.vel 3: 0.084714 
[31m[ERROR] [1386694869.787273642]: IK not found
```

I can not understand what the problem is...

[URDF file](http://files.mail.ru/395870D0ECFC42FABCC7E46C2270855A)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109061/ik-with-kdl/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Are you sure the end position can be reached? Also your delta_twist.vel 1 value seems to jump around, could it be that your solution is near a singular position of the Chain. Could you provide us the Chain you are using?

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2013-12-11**:
Yes, I'm sure, because I use rviz (with joint_state_publisher, robot_state_publisher and tf) to get values of joints and cartesian coordinates. I attached urdf file to above.

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2013-12-12**:
Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your URDF describes a 3 DOF manipulator. However, your solver sets 6 constraints on the end effector (3 position + 3 orientation). In general, it is not possible to satisfy the 6 constraints only with 3DOF. The jacobbian you are using is 6x3. That means that it tries to satisfy the 6 constraints. That is because you get those incorrect and strange solutions.

And that is why I developed the solution described in http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/IK-with-KDL-td1867716.html?

It worked well for me reaching a 3D position with a 3DOF manipulator.

Another choice is adding 3 "fake revolute artificial joints" in the end effector.

However, the best solution should be change the jacobbian matrix to a 3x3  matrix that only considers the final position of the end effector (ignoring its final orientation). If you (or someother) develop this solution, please, share it with us :-).

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2013-12-17**:
But I have same solution in hp_chainiksolverpos_nr_jl.cpp:
if(Equal(delta_twist.vel,Vector::Zero(),eps))   break;
delta_twist.rot ignored.
And I do:
ik_solver_vel.setWeightTS(matrix_Mx);
Last three diagonal values are 0 in matrix_Mx.
Is this like your solution?)

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2013-12-18**:
The weight matrix was designed to break the numeric search if a partial solution (in position but not in the orientation)was found. It doesn't improve the numeric search itself. It still may be very hard to find even a "partial solution" if the kinematic characterization or the goal is not suitable.